# How to find instance of class which is calling method

Tags: java

I know about way how to find which class is calling my method, but this is not sufficient to my.

I have a problem that I have about 200 instances of same class(base class) and they have unique identifier which I can use for analysing problem.

Is there some way, how to find which instances called some method?

I know that debugger allow it, can I do it some how from a code?

Comment: You're going to have to pass that information around if you want it.

Comment: It sounds like very broken code if the member needs to walk up the stack and reflectively analyse the mmember that called it. Pass parameters that a method needs into that method.

Comment: Sorry, passing parameter is not possible - it is huge project based on code, which is not modifiable.

Comment: The need is that at some point we know there is a problem, and it can be caused by structure of data, which are done by user of application - so I need to identify which instance caused a problem, so user can fix his data

Answer (score 1):

You'd pass a reference for that instance to the method being called.  For example, say you have two objects:

```
class ObjectA {
    public void methodA() {
        new ObjectB().methodB();
    }
}

class ObjectB {
    public void methodB() {
        // How can I know who called me?
    }
}
```

If `MethodB` needs to know which instance of `ObjectA` called it, then it would accept that information as a parameter:

```
class ObjectA {
    public void methodA() {
        new ObjectB().methodB(this);
    }
}

class ObjectB {
    public void methodB(ObjectA caller) {
        // "caller" is who called me
    }
}
```

There are lots of ways to tweak this.  For example, maybe any given instance of `ObjectB` should have a reference to the `ObjectA` which *created* it:

```
class ObjectA {
    public void methodA() {
        new ObjectB(this).methodB();
    }
}

class ObjectB {

    private final ObjectA caller;

    public ObjectB(ObjectA caller) {
        this.caller = caller;
    }

    public void methodB() {
        // "caller" called me
    }
}
```

Or perhaps you don't want to couple the two objects together and want a more generic approach.  You claim that the objects have some kind of identifier, what is that identifier?  A `String` perhaps?

```
class ObjectA {

    private String identifier;

    // other code

    public void methodA() {
        new ObjectB().methodB(identifier);
    }
}

class ObjectB {
    public void methodB(String callerID) {
        // "callerID" identifies who called me
    }
}
```

Comment: This is some think I know, but it doesn't solve my problem. I can't pass the information. If I would creating new project, I would do it in this way, but it is not possible now - reason I am asking for getting instance from reflection and not passing it as a parameter.